# Use Proxy Server on Apple Watch?

Tags: apple-watch, charles-proxy, proxy-server

Is there any way to enable / configure proxy server of Wi-Fi on the Apple Watch?

We would like to test something via Charles so we would like to connect the Apple Watch with Charles.

I didn't find any settings on the Watch, and although I turned on proxy on the iPhone, traffics from the Watch doesn't appear in Charles :( .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. It turns out it will just use the iPhone's proxy configuration. Although I must **first install the Charles SSL certificate on the iPhone**! After installation, the traffic appeared.

Link to get the certificate: https://charlesproxy.com/getssl

Answer (score 0):

I've installed Charles SSL certificate on the iPhone, but https requests reject yet. iOS 10, iOS 11
Any options to install ssl cert on Apple Watch, 'cause https://charlesproxy.com/getssl doesn't work for Watch